How to fold or expand the wingtips on Boeing 777?
I have heard that some Boeing 777's wingtips can be folded when the aircraft is on ground. However, I didn't find the switch to control the wingtips. Where are these switches?
Btw, I use FlightGear and the original 777 from the FlightGear official hangar.

This is only possible in the 777X, not any other 777 variants like the 777-200 or 777-300.
Also questions related to issues in flight simulators are off-topic here.
In the 777X, there is a switch in the overhead panel that can be used to extend and retract the wing tips when required.
It looks like this,

Here's the usage procedure diagram of this feature,


Oh, that's my mistake. Sorry. I'll delete or edit this question later

@GordonZhang, I'm not sure if you need to because your question also has non-flight sim related parts... leave it as is..

All right. I'll keep this question here. Anyway, thank you for answering. At least now I know how to control the wingtips when I have a 777X in Flight sim. :-)

What does "automation FOLDS wingtips" mean, does the switch move automatically as well?

@Bergi yes correct, when the airspeed goes below 50 knots G/S the switch automatically moves into the folded position and the wingtips begin to fold. At set speeds it automatically goes up too
Source: https://theaircurrent.com/technology/how-the-777xs-folding-wing-tips-work/

Is it somewhat ironic that this answer reminds the poster about the on-topic rules for flight simulation, but then includes a screen grab from a flight simulator to support the answer? ;)

@TypeIA, there's plenty of pics of the real thing too, for example the answer below has one...
I felt simulator picture would be fine because the question is asking of a simulator too. If it wasn't related to the simulator at all then I would find and source a real image.

The switch is located on the overhead panel next to the passenger signs:

(image source: LinkedIn: The Boeing 777X Folding WingTip (FWT) operation.)
Note however, that only the Boeing 777X series has the folding wingtips. All previous Boeing 777 models do not have that folding wingtips and therefore no associated switch.
I don't know which variant you are flying in the simulator, but since the 777X is not yet certified, I guess it is an older variant.

It's obviously just a result of unintended humourous cropping, but for a split second my brain wondered what happens when you flip the switch on the right to turn the wings off. ;)

@EndAntisemiticHate Well, that's when you get the once-in-a-career "Wing Off Light" illuminating!

@RalphJ LOL! It's preferable to fly with that light off, but if it goes on... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyCLuDjU57c and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxJcEz3h4tU

What happens to the flight dynamics if you fold the tips while in flight, for example by accidentally flipping the switch when turning off the seatbelt sign? Do they break off or what?

@Richard the switch doesn't work in flight, it's full fly-by-wire meaning a computer controls the wingtips. It won't listen to the switch position unless the weight-on-wheels sensor tells it that the aircraft is on the ground.

@Bianfable - And if it goes off by accident?

@Richard I believe the folding mechanism is also designed so that it can't unlock under load.

@user71659 - Well that's no fun at all
